# Why is my image not being loaded into the background of my Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, django

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried a couple different ways as shown below to get my image to be the background of my Jumbotron but none of them are working. I know it's not an issue with loading static or anything like that because  doing img src= straight into the Jumbotron section works but it it's not actually the background of Jumbotron. So what am I doing wrong here?

**home.html/styles**

```
    .JumboHeaderImg{
  background-image: url("/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static/images/jumbo.jpg");

}
   .JumboHeaderImg{
  background-image: "{% static 'images/jumbo.jpg' %}";

     <div class="jumbotron  JumboHeaderImg">
```

**style.css**

```
.jumbotron{

background-image: url('{% static "images/jumbo.jpg"%}');
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this:

```css
.jumbotron{
    background-image: url('{% static "images/jumbo.jpg"%}');
}
```

Is not going to work unless you render the CSS file as a template, otherwise the url will be literally `{% static "images/jumbo.jpg"%}` because the tag `static` is no parsed.

In order to set you image url you can use inline styles in your template, so your static tag will work. If you stll want to do it in the css file you have to harcode the image url.

With inline style should be like:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('{% static "images/jumbo.jpg"%}')">
...
</div>
```